# Phonon class not present in PyQt5

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

I am using PyQt5 version to develop simple Audio player but it's fail to import Phonon class.

I want to play simple mp3 file

Hope to hear from you soon

Answer (score 9):

There is no Phonon in Qt5. New [QtMultimedia](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtmultimedia-index.html) module should be used:

```
import PyQt5.QtCore as C
import PyQt5.QtMultimedia as M
import sys

app=C.QCoreApplication(sys.argv)

url= C.QUrl.fromLocalFile("./some.mp3")
content= M.QMediaContent(url)
player = M.QMediaPlayer()
player.setMedia(content)
player.play()

player.stateChanged.connect( app.quit )
app.exec()
```

Before you ask, you need PyQt5.QtMultimedia module, witch might not be provided with PyQt5 Core library. Ubuntu have separated packed python3-pyqt5.qtmultimedia.

Comment: You also need the `libqt5multimedia-plugins` package in Ubuntu 15.04.

Comment: The package seems to be called libqt5multimedia5-plugins but it doesn't solve the problem on 16.04 of some missing plugins...