# QtMultimedia MP3 audio playback

Tags: python-3.x, audio, pyqt5, qtmultimedia

I want to play an audio (MP3) file when the QmainWindow opens and have used the script from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23953944/phonon-class-not-present-in-pyqt5#_=_). This is what my code looks like:

```
app = QApplication(sys.argv)

window = MainWindow()
window.show()

url = QUrl.fromLocalFile("./sound2.mp3")
content = QMediaContent(url)
player = QMediaPlayer()
player.setMedia(content)
player.play()

player.stateChanged.connect(app.quit)

app.exec_()
```

There is no problem running the script except that when I close the app the MP3 sound file continues to play when it should in fact stop. How do I modify the code? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `app.lastWindowClosed.connect(player.stop)`.

Comment: @ekhumoro Thank you, that worked perfectly.