# pyqt5 looping mp3 file

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, audio-player, qtmultimedia

I want to loop an audio file and using a combination of [THIS CODE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43018205/qtmultimedia-mp3-audio-playback) (my orignal question with solution) and [THIS CODE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37690616/play-background-music-in-a-loop-qt) (Qt C example) managed to create this:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtMultimedia import *
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = QCoreApplication(sys.argv)

    playlist = QMediaPlaylist()
    url = QUrl.fromLocalFile("./sound2.mp3")
    playlist.addMedia(url)
    playlist.setPlaybackMode(QMediaPlaylist.Loop)

    content = playlist()
    player = QMediaPlayer()
    player.setMedia(content)
    player.play()

    app.lastWindowClosed.connect(player.stop)
    app.exec()
```

However, this code does not work and the error reported is:

TypeError: arguments did not match any overloaded call:
  addMedia(self, QMediaContent): argument 1 has unexpected type 'QUrl'
  addMedia(self, object): argument 1 has unexpected type 'QUrl'

Where am I going wrong with the code? Any help is most appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You were close.  Try the following...

```
playlist = QMediaPlaylist()
url = QUrl.fromLocalFile("./sound2.mp3")
playlist.addMedia(QMediaContent(url))
playlist.setPlaybackMode(QMediaPlaylist.Loop)

player = QMediaPlayer()
player.setPlaylist(playlist)
player.play()
```

Comment: Hi @shao.lo. Thanks for the solution (I sorted this out a couple of weeks ago but forgot this post) - I'll leave it up in case someone else is looking for the solution